# maxFontSizeMultiplier prop all <Text/>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I set the prop `maxFontSizeMultiplier={1}` for all `<Text/>` components in my application without having to create a custom one?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to globally change them, so @SterlingArcher's answer is probably the best approach, using `TextWrapped` wherever you use `Text`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a wrapper component around `<Text />`. I don't use react native, so if there's obvious non-compatibilities just convert them.

This wrapper convention allows you to customize native components without having to manipulate the source code of built in/lib components.

```
const TextWrapped = (props) => {
    return(
        <Text {...props} maxFontSizeMultiplier={1} />
    );
}

export default TextWrapped;
```

Comment: To ensure that this `TextWrapped` component is able to use all of the `Text` props, you should update it like so: `const TextWrapped = props => (<Text {...props} maxFontSizeMultiplier={1} />)`

Comment: To allow overriding `maxFontSizeMultiplier`, place it *before* `{...props}` like so: `<Text maxFontSizeMultiplier={1} {...props} />`

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve the goal with the following code which needs to be placed "index.js".

```
import { Text } from 'react-native';

Text.defaultProps = {
  ...Text.defaultProps,
  maxFontSizeMultiplier: 1,
};
```

Comment: That is the real answer.

Comment: if youre using typescript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65193181/12104850

Answer (score 0):

check this widget .The defaultProps will be used to ensure that this.props.maxFontSizeMultiplier will have a value if it was not specified by the parent component.

```
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const TextWrapper = (props) => {
    return <Text {...props} />
}

TextWrapper.defaultProps = {
  maxFontSizeMultiplier: 1,
};

export default TextWrapper;
```