# Initializing Text.defaultProps with Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I just started rewriting my existing react-native project from js to typescript.
To disable font scaling, I set `Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling` to `false` at the beginning of App.js and it worked well.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
...

if (Text.defaultProps == null) Text.defaultProps = {};
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling=false; 

export default function App () {
  . . .
}
```

When I changed from `App.js` to `App.tsx` and ran `tsc`, I get following typescript error:

```
App.tsx:16:10 - error TS2339: Property 'defaultProps' does not exist on type 'typeof Text'.
16 if (Text.defaultProps == null) Text.defaultProps = {};
```

I tried to search similar issues and typescript documents but failed. How can I solve this error?

Comment: as same as mine, it's not working.

Answer (score 8):

Want solutions to prevent font autoscaling in app.tsx?

```
import {Text, TextInput} from 'react-native';


interface TextWithDefaultProps extends Text {
    defaultProps?: { allowFontScaling?: boolean };
}

interface TextInputWithDefaultProps extends TextInput {
    defaultProps?: { allowFontScaling?: boolean };
}


((Text as unknown) as TextWithDefaultProps).defaultProps = ((Text as unknown) as TextWithDefaultProps).defaultProps || {};
((Text as unknown) as TextWithDefaultProps).defaultProps!.allowFontScaling = false;
((TextInput as unknown) as TextInputWithDefaultProps).defaultProps = ((TextInput as unknown) as TextInputWithDefaultProps).defaultProps || {};
((TextInput as unknown) as TextInputWithDefaultProps).defaultProps!.allowFontScaling = false;

const App = () => {
    ...
}
```

this Code actually working on my source

Answer (score 2):

Are you using React Native Paper? You may be importing the wrong `Text`.

The following works, but I don't see these properties on the default React Native `Text`.

```
import { Text } from "react-native-paper";

if(Text.defaultProps == null) Text.defaultProps = {};
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

If this happens to be the case, you may have just discovered why TypeScript is useful.

However, the way I would do this is to actually just create a custom component that wraps the one I want to apply defaults too. Something like this that takes all the same props as the original and then I override them with some defaults.

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import { Text, TextProps } from 'react-native';

const defaultProps: TextProps = {
    allowFontScaling: false
}

const CustomText: FC<TextProps> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
    return <Text {...{ ...defaultProps, ...props }}>{children}</Text>
}

export default CustomText;
```

Then, I just use the custom component in the place of the one from the library.

```
function Component() {
    return <CustomText>Hello</CustomText>
}
```

Lastly, if you want to call these properties anyway. You can always cast the Text as any and the TypeScript compiler won't complain anymore.

```
import { Text } from 'react-native';

if ((Text as any).defaultProps == null) (Text as any).defaultProps = {};
(Text as any).defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I am already using my own CustomText component for some reason, your approach is fairly good to me. :)

Comment: Cool, added a simple solution to make your current code compile as well. You can cast something as any and TypeScript won't type check it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

@Todd Skelton's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65192671/4402041) helped me a lot, thank you, but I think the point can be made more concisely:

```
import { Text, TextProps } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
  
type ChildrenProps = {
  readonly children: React.ReactNode
}
 
export const TextWithoutOSScale = ({
  children,
  ...props
}: ChildrenProps & TextProps): React.ReactElement => {
  return (
    <Text allowFontScaling={false} {...props}>
      {children}
    </Text>
  )
}
```